# json2 stringify

Tags: jquery

I have seen several posts about json2.js and the stringify method it provides.  However, the posts I have seen are from almost a year ago.  Is there a better library to use today or does jQuery directly support stringify functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `JSON` object has been defined in ECMAScript 5th ed, and is already available in most modern browsers. No special setup is needed. Calling,

```
JSON.stringify(someObject)
```

will spit out a JSON representation of the passed in object. If you want compatibility for older browsers, then simply include Crocford's json2.js on your page. json2.js will use the browser's native implementation, if available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.serialize()` method on a form to give you a JSON string of a jQuery form object. It's usually what I use if I'm doing an AJAX POST request.

Example:

```
<form id="SomeForm">
    <input name="hello" type="hidden" value="world" />
</form>

<script>
    $('#SomeForm').serialize(); // '{ "hello": "world" }'
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So this will serialize to json elements in a form.  What if I have a js object?  Is there another method (save from writing your own) besides json2.js?

Comment: Doesn't `serialize` give URL encoded parameters instead of JSON?

Comment: @Anurag - you are correct.  after closer examination it produces a formatted querystring, not json